# Chaining JavaScript (ES6) Proxy object

Tags: javascript, proxy, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to do this:

```
x.where('age').gt(20);

x.__calls  // [['where', ['age']], ['gt', [20]]]
```

`where` and `gt` are just examples. I do not know what functions will be called, they might be anything, and they don't do anything apart from filling the `__calls` array.

So far I have the following code which uses ES6's [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object

```
var x = new Proxy({ 
    __calls: [] 
}, {
    get: function (target, name) {
        if (name in target) {
            return target[name];
        } else {
            return () => {
                target.__calls.push([name, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)]);
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If I remove the `return x` line, I can do `x.where('age'); x.gt(20)` to get the correct `__calls`. However, with the `return x`, it goes into infinite recursion for some reason...

Comment: @world more mongoose-named-scopes woes

Comment: For future searchers, I think I've come up with a solution to a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886355/capturing-all-chained-methods-and-getters-using-a-proxy-for-lazy-execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `console.log(name)` to find out what calls were responsible for the infinite recursion, and it turns out it was `inspect` and `constructor`. So I just blacklisted them :)

```
var x = new Proxy({ 
    __calls: [] 
}, {
    get: function (target, name) {
        if (name in target || name === 'inspect' || name === 'constructor') {
            return target[name];
        } else {
            return function() {
                target.__calls.push([name, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)]);
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
});
```